# API response does not return OrderArray.Order.SellerUserID

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I have a question about ebay trading api.

I'm trying to get the information about my purchases so I can follow up on late/failed deliveries.
I have managed to get almost all of the information I need, however I just can't seem to work out how to get eaby-api to return the seller user id.

```
api = Trading(
    config_file=None,
    appid=load_settings['appid'],
    certid=load_settings['certid'],
    devid=load_settings['devid'],
    token=load_settings['token'],
    timeout=None
)
response = api.execute('GetOrders', {
    'CreateTimeFrom': create_time_from,
    'CreateTimeTo': create_time_to,
    'OrderRole': 'Buyer',
    'DetailLevel': 'ReturnAll',
    'Pagination': {
        'EntriesPerPage': 100,
        'PageNumber': page
        }
    })
data = response.dict()
print(data)
```

I read in the docs that to get **OrderArray.Order.SellerUserID** you have to change the **DetailLevel**
However even if I set **'DetailLevel': 'ReturnAll'** I do not get SellerUserID in my response.
Is there something I'm over looking?

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getorders.html#DetailLevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the information was there, just not in the place the docs said.
I found it at
`response.dict()["OrderArray"]["Order"]['MonetaryDetails']['Payments']['Payment']['Payee']`

Answer (score 0):

using eBay API `getOrders`, without any `sdk`

it returns correctly the `SellerUserID` even without setting `DetailLevel` to `ReturnAll`